# Terminal and web browser combination

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, window-manager, tmux, browser

I often use only two applications, **terminal** and **web browser**.

I like the `tmux` application which enables to split a terminal window into more regions. I noticed that I can open `lynx` in another region and have a browser and terminal displayed at the same time. But command-line browsers aren't very nice for viewing web pages.

**Konqueror** is able to split a web page into more regions. It would be great if there was a browser which could display a web page in one region and a terminal in another region.

Is there already a program combining web browser and terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job of splitting the screen into regions is normally devoted to the window manager. Many window managers have facilities to quickly set up or recall a window arrangement.

If you find that you divide your screen between unobscured windows often, you may want to switch to a [tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager). Choosing a tiling WM has already been discussed on this site: [Need advice in choosing a tiling WM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/need-advice-in-choosing-a-tiling-wm); [Tiling windows in GNOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305/tiling-windows-in-gnome).

Comment: That's great and yet more general solution than I was looking for. Could you recommend me something for the beginner with quick learning curve (and later I would try something more sophisticated)? I'm not using GNOME (I'm using XFCE). I have a small display 15" so it would be great if the manager could turn off the graphical needlessness (the bar with name of the application, resizing buttons like _ [] x).

Comment: @xralf: Tiling WMs are generally good at not wasting screen real estate. You'll find recommendations in the first question I link to.

Answer (score 2):

Try Firefox plus the [FireSSH](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firessh/) add-on.

If you only want a local terminal, you can make it SSH to `localhost`.

By default, FireSSH wants to open SSH sessions in a separate window, but you can configure it to open them in a tab instead. That's not the same thing as a split window, I realize, but it does let you toggle back and forth between the two with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and -<kbd>PageDn</kbd>.

Comment: Looks interesting. I only have to upgrade my firefox and there is only .tar.gz file (not debian package) so I have to backup first if something happened. It's good that this solution exists but split window would be better than new tab. ctrl-pageUp is similar as alt-tab. I will try it with [yubnub](http://yubnub.org/kernel/ls?args=split) split command if it helps.

Comment: I tried FireSSH with yubnub, and it didn't work. Firefox does have the ability for add-ons to create side-bars (prime example: Firebug) so maybe you could ask the add-on's author to add this feature.

Comment: Good idea. If they would combine some firebug functionality with FireSSH functionality. Maybe it would be possible to code it, if chrome windows have this flexibility.