# Gnome Shell window snap to quarters of screen

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, window-management

I love the window snap feature of the Gnome 3 shell. However, it only allows you to maximize windows or to snap to the left or right half of the screen. Is there a way to snap to quarters of the screen? Maybe some shell extension I'm unaware of?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048693/how-can-i-snap-a-window-in-a-corner-with-18-04

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are several extensions on the [GNOME extensions site](https://extensions.gnome.org/) which can give you various modes of "snapping" your windows. One that works particularly well is [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/).

[image: ss of gTile]

#### References

- [Keyboard Shortcuts GNOME 3](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was searching for. But: how do I install it? When I go to the extensions page and flip the switch, the message pops up, I click install nothing happens. I'm running Gnome 3.12 so I also tried downloading it from the git repository, extracted the zip, and changed "3.10" to "3.12" in metadata.json, recompressed it and tried to install in using the Gnome Tweak tool which gives me an "Invalid Extension" notification. Any idea?

Comment: @Jonas - what browser are you using? You can install these extensions via Firefox. Once installed you can get at the extensions a couple of ways, I generally run this from the shell: `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`. The pulldown should have your extensions listed.

Comment: Now it's showing up. Problem is, when I active gTile, I can arrange the windows as one would expect, *but I can't close gTile*. Clicking on the x will just brings the gTile window up again in the same location. I could only resume work after disabling the extension. Pretty strange. Maybe it is indeed not compatible with gnome 3.12 yet.

Comment: @Jonas - that's very much a possibility. The other 2-3 extensions that deal w/ tiling had comments on them to that effect as well.

Comment: At the moment the extension is working fine with 3.12, the author even recommends 3.12 since 3.10 has some window placement bugs.

Answer (score 23):

See **[shelltile](https://github.com/emasab/shelltile/blob/master/README.md)**.

It's a neat little extension that allows the corner snapping, as well as other **very** useful features.

*Update:* Due to recent versions of Gnome being unsupported, consider **[Tiling-Assistant](https://github.com/Leleat/Tiling-Assistant)**. An alternative with similar interface.

Comment: Brilliant. The UX seems to be much more intuitive than gTile's. Thanks for pointing this one out.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer -- shelltile does exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: Agreed. This is much better. Works as extending the native tile functionality, so is certainly more intuitive.

Comment: unfortunately, this extension is incompatible with current gnome versions

Comment: I have updated the answer with a suitable alternative for now, hopefully the author can get help in maintaining it.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest the extension [Put Window](https://github.com/negesti/gnome-shell-extensions-negesti).

It has many customization options, ability to modify hot keys, etc.. Similar to all extensions it can be installed and activated at [extensions.gnome.org](http://extensions.gnome.org)

Comment: I like the Put Windows extension for Gnome too and detailed how to install it here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048693/how-can-i-snap-a-window-in-a-corner-with-18-04/1089033#1089033