# split windows in gnome-debian (stretch version) with shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

It is really useful the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> for moving windows to the left/right (technically "view split of left/right"). My version is gnome-debian (gnome 3.22.3) stretch (stable), but I want more custom shortcuts:

For example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to move one window to the bottom right part (useful for terminals), similar to the other shortcut but in the bottom part.

I don't know if there is an easy way to do this trough shortcuts, or if you need to modify some files, any tip will be welcome :)

NOTE: I mention terminals as an example, but I would like to do it with any windows if it's possible.

Comment: If you want to just move them you can customize shortcuts under `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings` in `dconf-editor` . If you want to snap them - i.e. move and resize to half/quarter of the screen - there's no such functionality included in the current `gnome-shell` afaik. Try [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) or [gtile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/)

Comment: If nothing else, please put your "SOLUTION" into the Answer box, as that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

(As noted in comments there are maybe easier ways to make it: [[Gnome Shell window snap to quarters of screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139730/gnome-shell-window-snap-to-quarters-of-screen))

Ok, I figure it out. I have installed trough terminal the `wmctrl` tool (`sudo apt-get install wmctrl`). It configures the X windows trough a command like  way. For my purpose, I use:

- `wmctrl -dG` -> to know the screen size (from what I know it can't move directly to bottom right without knowing what exact size it has). For my case, 1366x768 (replace the numbers with your screen-size) -> (1366/2=683, 768/2=384)
- `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,683,384` for placing it up-left corner
- `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,384,683,384` bottom-left
- `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,683,0,683,384` up-right
- `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,683,384,683,384` bottom-right
- in gnome settings -> keyboard -> go down where is a <kbd>+</kbd> sign -> add shortcuts
- you have to find another shortcuts you like cause it can't add <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>

NOTE: in order to work, the window has to be in no-max-sized