# Efficient window size manipulation

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, window-management

On Gnome, you can usually set a window to occupy half of the screen with <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>.

Is there any way I can bind hotkeys to manipulate window sizes more flexibly? e.g. bind a key to make window occupy left 2/3 of screen, or bind key to increment window size by a set amount?

This would be incredibly helpful because I have an ultra wide screen monitor

Comment: You may want to install `wmctrl` (if not already installed) and explore the possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some plugins that may be useful:

[shellshape](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/294/shellshape/)

[gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/)

[slinger](https://github.com/timbertson/slinger)

[also this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305/tiling-windows-in-gnome)